# Filename field in "Save as" dialog box loses focus

Tags: microsoft-word

When have to save a new version of a Word file, it has been my SOP to select an existing file with a similar name in order to pre-populate the filename field in the dialog box, and then edit the name.  This is so I don't have to retype an lengthy filename only to change two characters (for instance, if I have to create a new version of a file with today's date, I'll choose last week's file and change "12" to "19".) Recently, when I do this, as soon as I delete one character of the old file name, the field loses focus so the remaining edits are not captured.  This only happens if I select an existing filename to edit.  If I simply type the new file name, no problem.  And it seems only to happen with Word files.  I find this very annoying.  Does this happen to anyone else?

Feel free to add tags as you see fit

Comment: I would wonder if you have an application that is watching for similar actions and is interrupting this focus. Check in your Task Bar and Task Manager and disable any extraneous and unnecessary software configured to run when your computer starts, and see if the issue persists after a restart.

Comment: What is the version (2016, 2013, etc.) and build number (if 2016 it is on File > Account > About) of Word you are running? Are you running Window or OS-X Mac?